# Getting stuck at gradle build :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-3.1.0

After switching to Java 8 (below are the newly added lines) for our Android project, Gradle build always gets stuck at `:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug`.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
```

Please suggest how to reduce this build time. Before adding the above lines it was around 3 minutes most. Our gradle plugin version is `3.1.2`
It takes even more than 30 minutes for every first build, after clean build / branch change / Android Studio restart
[image: It takes even more than 30 minutes for every first build, after clean build / branch change / Android Studio restart]

Comment: did you tried invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @KaranMer yep, didn't help.

Comment: There's nothing to go on here. I recommend you do a `--scan`.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin? `3.3.0`?

Comment: @weston as suggested by you, I did a --scan, and as I said, `:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug` takes most of the time, 37 minutes 34 seconds out of 42 minutes 22 seconds total build time.

Comment: @NelsonOsacky no, we were having some other issues when tried to upgrade to gradle 3.3, so decided to postpone it to after the current sprint.

Comment: There's a lot more to a scan than timing. Look at the suggestions and memory usage for example. Share the scan url if you are comfortable. Share on asg if you like.

Comment: @weston couldn't find you in asg with Weston, posted the url as a reply to my post in ASG. Please help out.